# Is there any country other than the United States that recognize Israeli sovereignty over the Golan Heights?

Tags: united-states, israel, international, syria, annexation

> In 2019, the United States became the first country to recognizes
> Israeli rather than Syrian sovereignty over the Golan Heights.119 It
> may be argued that this move by the Trump Administration also reflects
> a realist policy toward recognition of borders, as Israel has, de
> facto, exercised effective control over the Golan Heights region since
> 1967.

https://engagedscholarship.csuohio.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2299&context=fac_articles

Is there any country other than the United States that recognizes Israeli sovereignty over the Golan Heights? The article mentions that the United States became the first country to recognize Israeli sovereignty over the Golan Heights, I am wondering if any other country decided to follow suit and recognize Israeli sovereignty over it.

Comment: I'd have guessed Bolsonaro, but apparently he didn't go as far as Trump on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Israeli_occupation_of_the_Golan_Heights&oldid=1211625410#International_views) to Wikipedia, none other

> In March 2019, the United States, which previously considered the Golan Heights to be occupied, became the first country to recognize Israeli sovereignty over the territory it has held since 1967. The rest of the international community continues to view the territory as Syrian, held under Israeli occupation.

FWTW, I suspect that if any other country does this [or did this but wiki is not updated somehow], it will most likely be among those [that](https://www.jta.org/2024/02/07/global/argentina-will-move-its-embassy-to-jerusalem-javier-milei-announces-during-emotional-visit) moved their embassy to Jerusalem, which this piece on Milei's recent visit to Israel lists:

> the embassy move would make Argentina the sixth country, and only the second major country, to relocate its embassy to Jerusalem. Since then-President Donald Trump moved the U.S. embassy in 2017, fulfilling a campaign pledge, four countries have followed: Papua Guinea, Kosovo, Honduras and Guatemala.